# Changing Partition Key for List Based Partition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm curious if this is even possible.

If I currently partition have a list partition based on `col1` and would like to move my partition structure to one that is based `col2`, do I need to re-create the table, drop the old table and rename the new table?

Or is there any easier way.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't go the create/drop/rename route?  Seems a straightforward approach.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change the partitioning on an existing table - one way or another you'll have to do the create/copy/drop/rename sequence.  There's a system package to assist with partitioning - can't recall the name right now - SYS.DBMS_PART or something like that.  Hunt for it and it may save you writing a pile of code.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: You might like to consider posting questions like this on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) - I personally think this would be a much better fit over there.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to physically move the rows because the whole point about partitioning is that the rows are co-located.  However there is an easier way to achieve this. I think online redefinition is the way to go with this.  Not only does it require less nursemaiding from you it maintains an interim version of the table which allows users to continue using the table.

In a nutshell the process is: create an empty version of your table with the new partitioning scheme and let DBMS_REDEFINITION do its magic.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#i1006821).

(NB: I have never actually used this method to change a partitioning key: but I have used it to turn a non-partitioned table into a partitioned table, and I don't see why it shouldn't also work in your scenario).